# I have a long equation but long enough to occupy two lines. I want to break it to improve readability. How can I break it?

Tags: equations

```
\begin{eqnarray}
\lim_{n\rightarrow +\infty }d(SAx_n,A^{2}x_n) \leq \frac{1}{3}\left[ \lim_{n\rightarrow +\infty }d(SAx_n,St)+\lim_{n\rightarrow +\infty }d(St,S^{2}x_n) 
+ \lim_{n\rightarrow +\infty }d(St,S^{2}x_n)\right]. \notag
\end{eqnarray}
```

Answer (score 0):

Here are 4 possibilities. Note this particular equation fits in a singleline if you have sensible margins (i.e. if you don't use margin notes). Also, `eqnarray` shouldn't be used anymore, as it leads to bad spacing. Use one of the `amsmath` environment instead.

```
\documentclass[11pt]{article}
\usepackage{showframe}
\renewcommand{\ShowFrameLinethickness}{0.3pt}
\usepackage{mathtools}

\begin{document}

\begin{align*}
\lim_{n\rightarrow +\infty }d(SAx_n,A^{2}x_n) \leq \frac{1}{3}\Bigl[ & \lim_{n\rightarrow +\infty }d(SAx_n,St)
 \\ + & \lim_{n\rightarrow +\infty }d(St,S^{2}x_n)
  + \lim_{n\rightarrow +\infty }d(St,S^{2}x_n)\Bigr].
\end{align*}
\bigskip

\begin{align*}
\lim_{n\rightarrow +\infty }d(SAx_n,A^{2}x_n) \leq \frac{1}{3}\Bigl[ \lim_{n\rightarrow +\infty }d(SAx_n,St)
 & +\lim_{n\rightarrow +\infty }d(St,S^{2}x_n) \\
 & + \lim_{n\rightarrow +\infty }d(St,S^{2}x_n)\Bigr].
\end{align*}
\bigskip

\begin{flalign*}
   & \mathrlap{\lim_{n\rightarrow +\infty }d(SAx_n,A^{2}x_n) \leq} \\
  & & \frac{1}{3}\Bigl[ & \lim_{n\rightarrow +\infty }d(SAx_n,St)
  +\lim_{n\rightarrow +\infty }d(St,S^{2}x_n) + \lim_{n\rightarrow +\infty }d(St,S^{2}x_n)\Bigr].
\end{flalign*}
\bigskip
\begin{align*}
   & \lim_{n\rightarrow +\infty }d(SAx_n,A^{2}x_n) \leq \\
  \frac{1}{3}\Bigl[ &\lim_{n\rightarrow +\infty }d(SAx_n,St)
  +\lim_{n\rightarrow +\infty }d(St,S^{2}x_n) + \lim_{n\rightarrow +\infty }d(St,S^{2}x_n)\Bigr].
\end{align*}

\end{document}
```

[image]